# Is there a need to call MediaRecorder::setCamera() again after MediaRecorder::reset()?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am just wondering if  there is a need to call **MediaRecorder::setCamera()** again after **MediaRecorder::reset()**?

For example (for testing purposes only) :

1. create (open) camera object for FRONT CAMERA
2. call **MediaRecorder::setCamera()** using the camera object created at no. 1
3. perform other operations which caused error in MediaRecorder
4. call **MediaRecorder::reset()** to return it to initialized state

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you have to call it again.

**reset()**  restarts the MediaRecorder to its idle state. After calling this method, you will have to configure it again as if it had just been constructed.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#reset%28%29

Comment: I also thought so. But, for some devices it still works even if you don't call setCamera() after reset(). For some devices, it doesn't that's why I am confirming.

Comment: the maker of the device must have done some customization in the behavior of the MediaRecorder.